# Why is $\ln(-x)$ the antiderivative of $x^{-1}$ if $x < 0$?

Tags: calculus

> In relation to this question,
>   [$\ln|x|$ vs.$\ln(x)$? When is the $\ln$ antiderivative marked as an absolute value?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778068/lnx-vs-lnx-when-is-the-ln-antiderivative-marked-as-an-absolute-value/778083#778083)
>
> "On the other hand, if $x$ takes negative values then the derivative of
>   $\ln(−x)$ is $x^{−1}$: you can check this by differentiation."

How?

$$ \frac d {dx} \ln(-x) = \frac 1 {-x} \cdot -1 = \frac 1 x$$

Now plug in a negative value for $x$ and you get $\frac 1 {-x}$. But if I do it right away, $\ln(-x) = \ln(x)$ and all is good.

What am I missing? Why does the order of substitution matter?

Thanks.

Comment: Plug a negative value for $x$ into $\frac{1}{x}$ and you get $\frac{1}{-x}$? No...

Comment: I just wanted to point out that for $x\lt 0$, $|x|= -x$

Comment: The derivative of $\ln(cx)$ is $\frac1x$ for _every_ $c\ne0$. (Note that, if $c$ is positive, we have $\ln(cx)=\ln c+\ln(x)$.

Answer (score 4):

"Now plug in a negative value for $x$ and you get $\dfrac{1}{-x}$."

No!
  $1/x$ is still $1/x$.  If $x = - (\text{something else})$ then you can say
$\dfrac{1}{x} = \dfrac{1}{-\text{something else}}$.  But the something else is not $x$.

Comment: Right, $\operatorname{something else}$ is not $x$, $\operatorname{something else}$ must be $-x$ since $x$ is $-\operatorname{something else}$. $1/x$ is $\operatorname{something completely different}$  I guess.